# Algorithm for nth roots of unity in symbolic radical form?

Tags: algorithms, computer-algebra

Roots of unity are trivial to find numerically--just evaluate $sin$ and $cos$ to whatever precision you require. But suppose (because it's true) that I want exact algebraic representations for symbolic manipulation.

Well, I could cheat and use polar form, and store exact algebraic representations of the magnitude and angle of a complex number--but polar forms do not make it easy to do addition or subtraction.

So, I would really like a way to generate, for any $n$, an algebraic expression tree for at least one primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity; and if there's a good way to generate all of them that's faster than just exponentiating the first one, that would be nice, too! Based on, e.g., [this page on number theory](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/rootsunity.html), that should always be possible, and that's maybe enough background to figure it out eventually, but I don't immediately see how to convert the worked examples there into a general algorithm, so a reference implementation or an explanation of the algorithm in pseudocode would be nice. Does such a thing exist, or is it easy to write up as an answer?

Comment: Are you looking at or for symbolic math libraries? Something like sympy.org ?

Comment: @Brannon If there's one that includes this algorithm, sure. Neither SymPy (https://www.sympygamma.com/input/?i=1%5E%281%2F5%29) nor WolframAlpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%5E%281%2F5%29) appear to actually compute these representations, though.

Comment: Weber, Andreas; Keckeisen, Michael. "Solving Cyclotomic Polynomials by Radical Expressions" seems to be what you want

Comment: Hm. That skips over the actual description of the algorithm to focus on the performance of the Maple package they wrote to implement it; but the earlier "Computing Radical Expressions for Roots of Unity" by Andreas Weber, which it references, seems promising.